# GUI Programming

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

When I run my GUI program, I get an error that says in automotive = Automotive(), line 63, has an attribute error that says Automotive has no attribute 'show_choice'. But in my program below, it is clearly stated. Why is it saying this and how can I fix this problem?

Here is the GUI program I have so far (where I'm having trouble):

```
def show_choice(self):
    self.message = 'You selected:\n'

    if self.cb_var1.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '1\n'
    if self.cb_var2.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '2\n'
    if self.cb_var3.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '3\n'
    if self.cb_var4.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '4\n'
    if self.cb_var5.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '5\n'
    if self.cb_var6.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '6\n'
    if self.cb_var7.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '7\n'

#Display the message in the info box.

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Selection', self.message)

#Create an instance for My Gui class.

automotive = Automotive()
```

Comment: Is the `def show_choice(self):...` inside a `class Automotive` declaration?

Comment: You are showing a `def` - maybe (and most certainly) it is outside your class definition.  
Show your whole class.

Comment: Yes because my code is so long it wouldn't show everything but it is under  the class Automotive:
    def __init__(self):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is most probably over indented i.e:

```
class Automotive():
    def __init__(self):
        ....
        def show_choice(self):
            self.message = 'You selected:\n'

            if self.cb_var1.get() == 1:
                self.message = self.message + '1\n'
            if self.cb_var2.get() == 1:
                self.message = self.message + '2\n'
            if self.cb_var3.get() == 1:
                self.message = self.message + '3\n'
            if self.cb_var4.get() == 1:
                self.message = self.message + '4\n'
            if self.cb_var5.get() == 1:
                self.message = self.message + '5\n'
            if self.cb_var6.get() == 1:
                self.message = self.message + '6\n'
            if self.cb_var7.get() == 1:
                self.message = self.message + '7\n'
```

Or:

```
class Automotive():
    def __init__(self):
        ....
def show_choice(self):
    self.message = 'You selected:\n'

    if self.cb_var1.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '1\n'
    if self.cb_var2.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '2\n'
    if self.cb_var3.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '3\n'
    if self.cb_var4.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '4\n'
    if self.cb_var5.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '5\n'
    if self.cb_var6.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '6\n'
    if self.cb_var7.get() == 1:
        self.message = self.message + '7\n'
```

The def should be at the same indentation as your init def:

```
class Automotive():
    def __init__(self):
        ....
    def show_choice(self):
        self.message = 'You selected:\n'

        if self.cb_var1.get() == 1:
            self.message = self.message + '1\n'
        if self.cb_var2.get() == 1:
            self.message = self.message + '2\n'
        if self.cb_var3.get() == 1:
            self.message = self.message + '3\n'
        if self.cb_var4.get() == 1:
            self.message = self.message + '4\n'
        if self.cb_var5.get() == 1:
            self.message = self.message + '5\n'
        if self.cb_var6.get() == 1:
            self.message = self.message + '6\n'
        if self.cb_var7.get() == 1:
            self.message = self.message + '7\n'
```

Comment: @Ashley, then your indentation is incorrect, add the class to your question

Comment: Thank you!! I forgot to put the () after the class Automotive and I didn't have the correct indentation.

Comment: @Ashley, no worries, you don't actually  need the `()` the indentation was the issue.

Comment: Oh, okay. (: I also have another quick question if I may. I read that there was a way that I could add the choices that were selected from the check buttons in this program. I haven't been able to find a calculation that seems to work. Do you know what the appropriate calculation would be? And how could I display the total of the selected?

Comment: Can you add the code to pastebin, it will be easier understand what you want if I can see the code

Comment: I have to bring three minions to see the minions so will have a look when I get a chance later, if you can add the full code it will also be easier